# What is the dimension of a scalar-by-vector derivative?

Tags: matrices, derivatives

I have seen two very distinguish versions that define a scalar-by-vector derivative $$\frac{\partial a^Tx}{\partial x}=a$$ and $$\frac{\partial a^Tx}{\partial x}=a^T$$ where both $a, x$ are column vectors. Two versions give very different dimensions, one is $(n \times 1)$ and the other is $(1 \times n)$, which will significantly affect the subsequent calculations involving multiplications on matrices.

I understand the first one, as I have used the first one frequently in my optimization course, but for the second one having a hard time to comprehend it. Could someone help explain?

**Updates:**

[Here's the exactly same question that I've asked on another forum](https://www.quora.com/How-you-define-a-scalar-by-vector-derivative), it might help clear some of the confusions.

Answer (score 0):

The intrinsic viewpoint: the [differential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_derivative) in a point is a linear function. But if the elements of space are considered column vectors, is very handy consider linear functions as row vectors because the evaluation will be simply the matrix product:
$$b(x) = (b_1,\dots,b_n)\pmatrix{x_1\cr\vdots\cr x_n} = bx.$$